# What has eight eyes but no i in the name?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

What has eight eyes with none in the name?

People travel from across USA to see this

Comment: Octo-oculus.   ....

Comment: I thought I had an answer that works, but unfortunately it's only 7 I's - rot13(Gur snpr bs n pybpx, jvgu Ebzna ahzrenyf, ohg bayl ba guerr, fvk, avar, naq gjryir.)  Close, but not quite...

Comment: The title is misleading.

Comment: I've closed this as _too broad_ for exactly the reasons Rubio gives. @Matthew, it seems like we've provided quite a range of answers for you to try...

Comment: (OP has updated the question, and I've withdrawn my comment. Unfortunately the edit has invalidated nearly every answer offered. I suspect, though, that most of those answerers had little objective reason to think their answers were anything better than guesswork, so hopefully nobody feels their efforts were wasted.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps

> A quartet.
>  (Or any other relevant group of four people)

Now that OP has added to the question, and provided a hint in comments below, I'll surmise

> that we're looking for a "quartet" that's a national attraction in the US.
>  The most notable one I can think of is this foursome right here:
>
>  [image: Wikimedia Commons https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Mount_Rushmore.jpg/800px-Mount_Rushmore.jpg]
>  (**Mount Rushmore**)

...which has eight eyes but no `I` in the name.

Comment: Or up to an octet of pirates

Comment: Aye aye, captain @DarkThunder

Comment: @DarkThunder p***i***rates?

Comment: @MrPie my apologies, I meant "morally challenged seamen"

Comment: @DarkThunder ;)

Comment: How about buccaneers?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I have two ears. So... $2?

Comment: Quartet is close, think of a famous quartet that people visit daily

Comment: @MrPie **pi**rates?

Answer (score 16):

How about

> A tarantula?

Since

> All spiders have eight eyes, and so you just need to name a type of spider which has no 'i' in its name e.g. a tarantula.

Comment: see i was trying to think of something more out of the box but it could be that simple lol

Comment: @Matthew that is the difficulty of riddles as much as the beauty thereof ;)

Comment: It is not tarantula

Comment: @Matthew Why not?

Comment: I assume the OP is trying to solve a puzzle and this is a clue, therefore he can try different answers until he finds a correct one. @Matthew, if this is the case, please can you source the puzzle?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use "Charlotte".

Comment: Not all spiders have eight eyes, and in fact some have none.  Tarantulas do have eight though.

Comment: @Matthew I *hope* it's not out of the box, I don't want one running around...

Comment: the source is a radio station in my area doing this challenge so the question is read out loud hence why i do not know the correct spelling of the word in question, what I do know so far is 

1) The answer is NOT SPIDER

2) The answer is NOT TARANTULA

Answer (score 9):

Unlikely yet still possible answers:

> A Nepalese [stupa](http://www.religionfacts.com/buddha-eyes), these Buddhist shrines have a pair of eyes looking in each of the four cardinal directions
>  An octet that agrees (eight ayes)
>  A small pack of needles
>  Some potatoes (the white sprouts are called eyes)
>  Two people who wear glasses (those who wear glasses are sometimes called four-eyes)
>  Some dresses. Hook and eye closures are used on some garments. Lots have a single hook and eye above the zipper but some have more.
>  A molting peacock (these would be the eyes on the tail feathers)

@stiv is probably correct but why not go all out?

Comment: Also, an "aye-aye" is some kind of lemur.

Comment: Thanks, @DarkThunder. I was trying to think of that. So presumably a zoo would work.

Comment: Speedy Gonzales working at zoo full of suspicious lemurs: "Ay, ay, ay! Each aye-aye eyes the other aye-ayes!"

Answer (score 6):

Possibly:

> A QWERTY Keyboard?

Because:

> The **I** Key, Two Sh**i**ft keys, Two **I**nsert keys, Two W**i**n keys, and Pr**i**ntScn? I'm uncertain if this is correct since a lot of keyboards would have different keys and different spellings/symbols.

Comment: I like this, but the Win keys usually don't have "Win" spelled out.

Answer (score 5):

Fun answer

> I got really excited when I noticed my "keyboard" has 8 i's in it. 
> Sad side is it can't be the answer since not every keyboard has this much i's and to specify it I must say "Turkish QWERTY keyboard" which has "i" in it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What about:

> I think there was an old Nintendo game called "8 eyes". The letter 'i' doesn't feature in the name and the 'eyes' were actually jewels so there are no actual eyes in it either.

Answer (score 2):

Serious answer:

> The alphabet itself has eight holes if you pick a font where "g" has two holes: abdgopq, and "alphabet" has no i's in its name.

---

And just for fun answer:

> Some letters have holes in them, depending on your font. I'll pick the set "abdgopq" which have one "eye" each.
>  `cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep -E "^([^abdgopq]*[abdgopq][^abdgopq]*){8}$" | grep -v i` returns 127 results, including some fun words like:
>  
>      abracadabra
>      gobbledygook
>      paradoxology
>      photographable
>      propaganda
>      vagabondage

Comment: if you do caps lock, there are eight holes, regardless of font: ABDOPQR :)

Answer (score 0):

> A **shoe** may have 4 or more sets of eyelets for the laces ...

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  We generally put Spoiler tags around answers to avoid revealing the solution to someone who wants to attempt the puzzle on their own.  I’ve added them for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about

> Ben Hur's team of four horses.

Comment: Oh my... I believe it should have a fuller explanation with some added context, but I think this can be notified with a comment, whereas using a recommendation of deletion is quite harsh, if not gratuitous. My apologies. I was being highly incompetent when reviewing this.

Comment: Edited to be a little more explicit as to how the total of eight is reached.